# Why all the relative URLs become absolute?

Tags: html

Downloaded a php software and put in /var/www/Registration directory (in particular, index.php is in this directory). This page references some images like:

```
  <img src="assets/img/01.jpg" alt="Pic 1" />
```

The problem is, when I point my browser to

```
  http://myServer/Registration,
```

HTML page is fine but the images can't load.  Using google Chrome developer console, I saw my browser (chrome) is making request to

```
  http://myServer/assets/img/01.jpg,
```

it should have requested

```
  http://myServer/Registration/assets/img/01.jpg.
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have a `<base>` tag in your header? And does the URL of the page you've got opened also have the `/Registration` in it, or is that just on your server's files? It's probably one of those two problems. **EDIT** nevermind I didn't see the answer posted to it when I was in the SO review queue. I'm leaving this comment for future people who might find it useful though.

Comment: Thanks @Joeytye50 for the comment anyway. Wish I posted the question earlier, that way, I may see your answer and scratch less on my head.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out third party software added a line to the HTML

```
<base href="http://myServer">
```

Be warned that the base tag can bring in more confusion than convenience!  It may cause your end-users lose lots of hairs :-)